# calculation of $\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}(1-x+x^2)dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> Compute the definite integral
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}(1-x+x^2)\,dx
> $$

**Failed Attempt:**

Let $1-x+x^2=t$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
(2x-1)\,dx &= dt\\
dx &= \frac{1}{(2x-1)}dt
\end{align}
$$

Changing the limits of integration, we get

$$\int_{1}^{1}\tan^{-1}(t)\cdot \frac{1}{(2x-1)}dt = \int_{1}^{1}\tan^{-1}(t)\cdot f(t)dt = 0
$$

where $f(t)=\frac{1}{(2x-1)}$.

Is it true that $\int_{a}^{a}f(x)dx = 0$? If not, then where have I made a mistake in my attempted solution?

Comment: $\arctan(1-x+x^2)$ is positive on $[0,1]$, so certainly the integral is not zero.  Also: for given $t$, equation $1-x+x^2=t$ has two solutions $x$.  So do the two halves $[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ separately, since $1-x+x^2$ is injective on each of those.

Comment: Seems tangent has some really odd integrals. Every one of these questions contain tan/arctan.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

HINT:

As $\displaystyle 1-x+x^2=\frac{(2x-1)^2+3}4>0$ for real $x,$

using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610261/simplifying-an-arctan-equation/610286#610286), $\displaystyle \tan^{-1}(1-x+x^2)=\cot^{-1}\left(\frac1{1-x+x^2}\right)$

Now, we know $\displaystyle\cot^{-1}\left(\frac1{1-x+x^2}\right)=\frac\pi2-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{1-x+x^2}\right)$

Again, $\displaystyle\tan^{-1}\left(\frac1{1-x+x^2}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x+1-x}{1-x(1-x)}\right)=\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}(1-x)$

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138310/show-that-2-tan-12-pi-cos-1-frac35/583359#583359), the last identity holds true if $\displaystyle x(1-x)\le1$ which is true as $\displaystyle x(1-x)=\frac{1-(2x-1)^2}4\le \frac14$ for real $x$

Finally, as $\displaystyle \int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx,$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1\tan^{-1}(1-x)dx=\int_0^1\tan^{-1}\{1-(\underbrace{1+0-x})\}dx=\int_0^1\tan^{-1}xdx$

Comment: wow, like a magic trick

Comment: @SalechAlhasov, thanks, please find the edited version

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks, I've added something more to the answer

Comment: @juantheron, Some related links : http://www.math.cmu.edu/~ploh/docs/math/3-telescope-solns.pdf, http://web.mit.edu/yisun/www/notes/trigtricks.pdf, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450352/infinite-series-telescoping and http://goo.gl/zb6pI0

Comment: Thanks lab bhattacharjee....

Comment: @juantheron, my pleasure. Hope I could make the idea clear

Answer (score 8):

While lab bhattacharjee's hint is indeed excellent, it's also perhaps too high-brow for many students to notice unless pointed out to them, so I'd like to offer an alternative hint based on standard methods instead of "tricks".

**Hint:** Integrating by parts,

$$\int\tan^{-1}{\left(1-x+x^2\right)}\,dx=x\tan^{-1}{\left(1-x+x^2\right)}-\int x\cdot\frac{-1+2x}{\left(1-x+x^2\right)^2+1}dx\\
=x\tan^{-1}{\left(1-x+x^2\right)}-\int\frac{x\left(2x-1\right)}{\left(1-x+x^2\right)^2+1}dx.$$

Then consider using partial fractions to evaluate this new integral.

Comment: Luckily, that quartic factors into $(x^2+1)(x^2-2x+2)$.